# Error: Cannot find module 'express'

Tags: javascript, express, typescript, webpack

I'm using webpack to compile my Express app (written in TypeScript). But I have some trouble running the compiled file.

**webpack.config.json**

```
const root = require('app-root-path').path;
module.exports = {
    entry: `${root}/server/server.ts`,
    target: 'node',
    externals: [
        /^[a-z\-0-9]+$/ 
    ],
    output: {
        filename: 'compiled.js',
        path: `${root}`,
        libraryTarget: "commonjs"
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.tsx', '.js'],
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.tsx?$/,
            exclude: `/node_modules/`,
            loader: 'ts-loader'
        }]
    }
}
```

When I try to run the compiled file I get this:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'express'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/compiled.js:717:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (/compiled.js:20:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/compiled.js:644:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/compiled.js:705:30)
    at __webpack_require__ (/compiled.js:20:30)
    at /compiled.js:63:18
```

Comment: post your package.json

Comment: Have you tried removing `exclude: `/node_modules/`,`? I suspect that ts-loader has problem finding express since the node modules directory is excluded.